# DAX formula to find second minimum with extra criteria

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I have a problem that involves two tables, one with some costs (table stops at value, I have put in Expected Value what I want to see in my explicit measure), one with cities sorted by clusters.

I need to create an explicit measure that returns the second minimum value for a given cluster and Expense.

Costs Table

| Date | City | Expense | Value | Expected Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | Paris | Electricity | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | Berlin | Electricity | 1 | 1 |
| 2020 | London | Electricity | 2 | 1 |
| 2020 | New York | Electricity | 0 | 0 |
| 2020 | Paris | Heating | 1 | 4 |
| 2020 | Berlin | Heating | 4 | 4 |
| 2020 | London | Heating | 12 | 4 |
| 2020 | New York | Heating | 7 | 7 |

Cluster Table

| City | Cluster |
| --- | --- |
| Paris | Europe |
| London | Europe |
| Berlin | Europe |
| New York | America |

Let's take the expected value for [Electricity] in [Europe] Cluster. I get a 1 as two lowest values are 1. For Heating, I get a 4 as second minimum value is a 4.
(New York returns zero for the purpose of example but clusters will not contain only one city.)

For now, I have this bit of code which doesn't take into account the Expense type and Cluster :

```
2ndMin:=minX(
        topN(countrows(ALL(Costs))-1;ALL(Costs);Costs[Value])
        ;Costs[Value])
```

Any idea how I should edit the code to include the two specifications above ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tricky, because of ties for the min value. The solution is to count the rows with the minimum value and if more than one return the minimum, else the second to minimum

```
SecondMin =
VAR CurrentCluster =
    SUMMARIZE( 'Costs', 'Cluster'[Cluster] )
VAR CurrentExpense =
    VALUES( Costs[Expense] )
VAR CostsPerClusterAndExpense =
    CALCULATETABLE(
        Costs,
        CurrentCluster,
        CurrentExpense,
        REMOVEFILTERS( 'Cluster' ),
        REMOVEFILTERS( 'Costs' )
    )
VAR MinValue =
    MINX( CostsPerClusterAndExpense, Costs[Value] )
VAR Min2Value =
    MINX(
        FILTER( CostsPerClusterAndExpense, Costs[Value] > MinValue ),
        Costs[Value]
    )
VAR Result =
    IF(
        COUNTROWS( FILTER( CostsPerClusterAndExpense, Costs[Value] = MinValue ) ) > 1,
        MinValue,
        Min2Value
    )
RETURN
    IF( NOT ISEMPTY( Costs ), Result + 0 )
```

Comment: I saved the sample pbix I used on my github, this is the direct link for the download https://github.com/SergioMurru/shared/raw/main/Lezira%20DAX%20formula%20to%20find%20second%20minimum%20with%20extra%20criteria/Lezira%20DAX%20formula%20to%20find%20second%20minimum%20with%20extra%20criteria.pbix

Comment: This is working perfectly. Thank you so much ! The only thing that seems to not work, because I haven't specified and thought the filters would do this job, is that the minimum is calculated for all years. If I have only one year selected, I would like the minimum to be based on that year alone. (optional, if multiple years selected, have the minimum be on all years selected). Is this a big change ?

Comment: Actually, only the optional part is left to solve. For now, I have created a 'CurrentYear' variable just like the cluster variable, and it works fine year by year !

Comment: You could try to use ALLSELECTED(Costs[Date]) instead of VALUES for the CurrentYear

Comment: Actually, I have a full date in my date column, I have a calendar table with "Year" field. So I built the variable with a summarize like you did for the clusters.

Comment: Good job!. In fact I was perplexed about the Date column containing the Year :)

Comment: Hello Sergiom, can you help me on one last bit ? 

Finally, I will simplify things and have one chart that shows 2nd min for any cities selected in my slicers for each expense that I show. 
Forget about dates and clusters, those will be filtered by slicers when needed. 

I will have Expense and City as my rows and want the second minimum for each City selected for a given expense if that makes sense.

I have given this many many tries trying to filter things but I'm not good enough with DAX atm :( Thanks a lot !